# Why do I get http response code 400 when testing controllers on Rails 3.1 with xhr requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, upgrade

I just upgraded from Rails 3.0 to Rails 3.1(.12). The problem is that I have some controller (functional) tests that were passing successfully, but fail after the upgrade.

The controller tests are about `xhr` requests. So, the following:

```
xhr :get, :operators, :account_id => @account.to_param, 
    :id => @existing_session.to_param

assert_response :success
```

is success on Rails 3.0, but it fails on Rails 3.1 with response being 400. Exact error is:

```
Expected response to be a <:success>, but was <400>
```

Has anyone seen that in the past? Maybe while upgrading from Rails 3.0 to Rails 3.1?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem and I would like to record that, just in case somebody else might have the same issue in the future.

My controller had the following statement:

```
# Enforce XHR only for operators
verify :only => [:operators], :xhr => true
```

which caused the `400` status code in the response. I had to remove that and it worked. To make sure that I handle `xhr` requests only, in the corresponding action I did something like:

```
if request.xhr?
 ....
else
 head status: :not_acceptable
end
```

and it works.